# Glsl 3.3+ using multiple textures in and out (cloth calculation in shaders)

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

We're trying to port a working cloth simulation calculated on cpu to be calculated using shaders on the gpu. The basic concepts is as follows: 2 shader passes, one to calculate the positions of each point in the cloth, and one to draw the cloth, and calculate the cloth normals. We're using 2 FBO's with 3 textures each for position, previous position and normals.

In the first shader pass we want to use the first FBO's textures as input, and write position and previous position to the second fbo's textures. 
Between pass 1 and 2 we extract the position data and use it to create vertex array of triangles rather than singular points for the drawing step. 
In pass 2 we use the new vertex array to draw the cloth, and use a geometry shader to recalculate the normals, send this to the fragment shader, and finally output this to the normals texture from the second FBO. Then the FBO's swap places for the next loop.

This is what we would like to happen. What happens now is that in the calculation step what's written to our textures seems to be completely unrelated to what goes on in our shader, and we suspect we have done something wrong linking the textures during the draw-loops. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

This output we get for every point is 0.664063 0.742188 0.839844 1.000000

Fragment shader:

```
#version 330
uniform sampler2D pos;
uniform sampler2D prev_pos;
uniform sampler2D normal;
uniform float damping;
uniform float mass;
uniform vec3 gravity;
uniform vec3 wind;
uniform float ts;
uniform vec2 texsize;
uniform vec2 patch_size;
uniform vec2 step;
uniform vec2 neighbours[12]; 
in vec2 frag_texcoord;

out vec4 outpos;
out vec4 outprev;

void main(void)
{
    float movable_l = floor(frag_texcoord.x+(1.0-3*step.x))+floor(frag_texcoord.y+(1.0-step.y));
    float movable_r = (1-floor(frag_texcoord.x+3*step.x))+(1-floor(frag_texcoord.y+step.y));
    float movable = movable_r*movable_l;
    vec3 curr_pos = texture(pos,frag_texcoord.yx).xyz;

    if(movable >0){
        vec3 p_pos = texture(prev_pos,frag_texcoord).xyz;
        vec2 neighbourtexcoord;
        vec3  neighbourpos;
        for(int n=0;n<12;n++){
            neighbourtexcoord = neighbours[n]*step;
            neighbourtexcoord += frag_texcoord;
            if(neighbourtexcoord.x<0.0 || neighbourtexcoord.x>(1.0-step.x)){
                continue;
            }
            if(neighbourtexcoord.y<0.0 || neighbourtexcoord.y>(1.0-step.y)){
                continue;
            }
            neighbourpos = texture(pos,neighbourtexcoord).xyz;
            vec3 d = curr_pos-neighbourpos;
            float dist = distance(curr_pos,neighbourpos);
            float idist = length(neighbours[n])*step.x;
            curr_pos += d*(1-(idist/dist));
        }
        vec3 windF = texture(normal,frag_texcoord).xyz*wind;
        vec3 acc = windF+gravity;
        float damp = 1-damping;
        vec3 vel = curr_pos-p_pos;
        curr_pos += acc*ts+vel;
    }
    outpos = vec4(curr_pos,1.0);
    outprev = vec4(texture(pos,frag_texcoord).xyz,0.0);
}
```

Vertex Shader:

```
#version 330
in  vec3 in_Position;
out vec2 frag_texcoord;


void main(void)
{
    gl_Position =vec4(in_Position, 1.0);
    frag_texcoord=in_Position.xy;
}
```

Main program:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include "SOIL.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cassert>
#include <string.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#ifdef __APPLE__
    #include <OpenGL/gl.h>
    #include "MicroGlut.h"
// uses framework Cocoa
#else
//  #include <GL/glut.h>
#endif
#include "GL_utilities.h"
#include "VectorUtils2.h"
#include "Cloth.h"

//#include "LoadTGA.h"


#define TIME_STEPSIZE2 0.5*0.5 

#define CHECK_GL_ERRORS assert(glGetError()==GL_NO_ERROR);

#ifndef M_PI
#define M_PI 3.14159265
#endif

static long count = 0;
static long limit = -1;
static float startTime;

static GLfloat view_rotx = 90.0, view_roty = 0.0, view_rotz = 70.0;
static GLuint gear1, gear2, gear3; // Was display lists, now are VAOs
static GLfloat angle = 0.0;

//The value that controls the wind speed
float windForceZ = 0.0;

int gear1Triangles=0, gear2Triangles=0, gear3Triangles=0;

GLuint program, verletShader,clothVao, clothVbo, clothNbo, clothTbo, quadVao, quadVbo; // Shader

GLint colorPos;
float projectionMatrix[16];

static GLfloat pos[4] = { 5.0, 5.0, 10.0, 0.0 };
static GLuint quad[]={  -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
                        1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
                        -1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
                        -1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
                        1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
                        1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f};

#define W 512
#define H 512

//------------a structure for FBO information-------------------------------------
typedef struct
{
    GLuint attachID[3];
    GLuint fb;
    GLuint rb;
    GLuint depth;
    int width, height;
} FBOstruct;

FBOstruct *fbo1, *fbo2;
GLenum color_attachments[] = { GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT2};

float *gVert;
float *gNorm;
float *data;
static int numVertices;
static float currentNormalsX, currentNormalsY, currentNormalsZ;

GLuint texture_img;
GLint location_Texture, location_texCoord;
#define vDensity 8
#define hDensity 8
#define cloth_width 20
#define cloth_height 20
Cloth cloth1(cloth_height,cloth_width,vDensity,hDensity);

int size = (vDensity-1)*(hDensity-1)*9*2;

Point3D gravity, tmp1, wind;

void init_glsl_stuff(){

      verletShader = loadShaders("verlet.vert", "verlet.frag");
      CHECK_GL_ERRORS
      glUseProgram(verletShader);
      float neighbourarray[24] = {1,0,0,1,1,1,-1,1,-1,0,1-1,2,0,0,2,-2,0,0-2};
      glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(verletShader,"pos"),0);
      glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(verletShader,"prev_pos"),1);
      glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(verletShader,"normal"),2);
      glUniform1f(glGetUniformLocation(verletShader,"damping"), 0.01); 
      glUniform1f(glGetUniformLocation(verletShader,"mass"), 1.0);
      glUniform3f(glGetUniformLocation(verletShader,"gravity"), 0.0,0.9,0.0);
       glUniform3f(glGetUniformLocation(verletShader,"wind"), 0.0,0.0,0.0);
      glUniform1f(glGetUniformLocation(verletShader,"ts"), 0.5*0.5);
      CHECK_GL_ERRORS
      glUniform2f(glGetUniformLocation(verletShader,"texsize"), (float)hDensity,(float)vDensity);
      CHECK_GL_ERRORS
      // eventuellt lägga till k värden för fjädrar
      glUniform2f(glGetUniformLocation(verletShader,"patch_size"), (float)cloth_width/((float)hDensity-1.0),(float)cloth_height/((float)vDensity-1.0));
      CHECK_GL_ERRORS
      glUniform2f(glGetUniformLocation(verletShader,"step"),1.0/((float)vDensity-1.0), 1.0/((float)hDensity-1.0));
       CHECK_GL_ERRORS
      glUniform2fv(glGetUniformLocation(verletShader,"neighbours"),12,neighbourarray);
       glBindFragDataLocation(verletShader, 0, "outpos");
       glBindFragDataLocation(verletShader, 1, "outprev");
       glLinkProgram(verletShader);
       printProgramInfoLog(verletShader);

      glUseProgram(0);


}


void addTexture(int width, int height,int int_method,GLuint mempos,float *data,int attachment_pos){


        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,mempos);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
        if (int_method == 0)
        {
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
        }
        else
        {
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        }


        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA16F, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, data);
        glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, attachment_pos, GL_TEXTURE_2D, mempos, 0);
}

//------------------------------------------------------------
//-----------------------FBO Init-----------------------------
//------------------------------------------------------------
void CHECK_FRAMEBUFFER_STATUS()
{
    GLenum status;
    status = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER);
    if (status != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
        fprintf(stderr, "Framebuffer not complete\n");
}
FBOstruct *initFBO(int width, int height, int int_method, float *positions, float *normals)
{

    FBOstruct *fbo = new FBOstruct();



    fbo->width = width;
    fbo->height = height;

    // create objects
    glGenFramebuffers(1, &fbo->fb); // frame buffer id
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo->fb);
    glGenTextures(3, fbo->attachID);
    addTexture(width,height,int_method,fbo->attachID[0],positions,color_attachments[0]);
    addTexture(width,height,int_method,fbo->attachID[1],positions,color_attachments[1]);
    addTexture(width,height,int_method,fbo->attachID[2],normals,color_attachments[2]);
    fprintf(stderr, "Framebuffer object %d\n", fbo->fb);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);

    return fbo;
}

//------------------------------------------------------------
//---------------------Draw on GPU----------------------------
//------------------------------------------------------------
void drawClothGPU(){

    glViewport(0, 0, H, W);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo1->fb);

    glDrawBuffers(3, color_attachments);    

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, fbo2->attachID[0]);

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, fbo2->attachID[1]);

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE2);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, fbo2->attachID[2]);

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glUseProgram(verletShader);

    glBindVertexArray(quadVao); 
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,quadVbo);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 18);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,0);


    glBindVertexArray(clothVao);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo2->fb);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, fbo2->attachID[0]);
    glReadBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0);         
        int s = hDensity*vDensity*4;
    data = new float[s];
    glReadPixels(0, 0, hDensity, vDensity, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, data);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);



    gVert = new float[size];
    glUseProgram(program);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, clothVbo);
    int count = 0;
    for(int x = 0; x<vDensity-1; x++){
        for(int y=0; y<hDensity-1; y++){
            //(x+1,y)
            printf("value : %f",data[4*(x + 1 + hDensity*y)]);
            gVert[count] = data[4*(x + 1 + hDensity*y)];
            gVert[count + 1] = data[4*(x + 1 + hDensity*y) + 1];
            gVert[count + 2] = data[4*(x + 1 + hDensity*y) + 2];
            //(x,y)
            gVert[count + 3] = data[4*(x + hDensity*y)];
            gVert[count + 4] = data[4*(x + hDensity*y) + 1];
            gVert[count + 5] = data[4*(x + hDensity*y) + 2];
            //(x,y+1)
            gVert[count + 6] = data[4*(x + hDensity*(y+1))];
            gVert[count + 7] = data[4*(x + hDensity*(y+1)) + 1];
            gVert[count + 8] = data[4*(x + hDensity*(y+1)) + 2];
            //(x+1,y+1)
            gVert[count + 9] = data[4*(x + 1 + hDensity*(y+1))];
            gVert[count + 10] = data[4*(x + 1 + hDensity*(y+1)) + 1];
            gVert[count + 11] = data[4*(x + 1 + hDensity*(y+1)) + 2];
            //(x+1,y)
            gVert[count + 12] = data[4*(x + 1 + hDensity*y)];
            gVert[count + 13] = data[4*(x + 1 + hDensity*y) + 1];
            gVert[count + 14] = data[4*(x + 1 + hDensity*y) + 2];
            //(x,y+1)
            gVert[count + 15] = data[4*(x + hDensity*(y+1))];
            gVert[count + 16] = data[4*(x + hDensity*(y+1)) + 1];
            gVert[count + 17] = data[4*(x + hDensity*(y+1)) + 2];

            count+=18;
        }
    }

    int num_vertices = (count)/3;
    int num_coordinates = count;

    GLfloat* pData = (GLfloat*)glMapBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, GL_READ_WRITE);
    memcpy(pData, &gVert[0], num_coordinates*sizeof(GLfloat));
    glUnmapBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER);

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, num_vertices);
    delete [] gVert;
    delete [] data;
    FBOstruct *tmp = fbo1;
    fbo1 = fbo2;
    fbo2 = tmp;
}



static void draw(void)
{




    //CPU
    //drawClothCPU(m);

    //GPU
    drawClothGPU();



    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

    glutSwapBuffers();
    count++;
    if (count == limit)
        exit(0);
    theTime = glutGet(GLUT_ELAPSED_TIME) / 1000.0;
    if (theTime >= startTime + 1.0)
    {
        //printf("%d fps\n", count);
        startTime = theTime;
        count = 0;
    }
}

static void
init(void)
{

    glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    init_glsl_stuff();  //first shader stuff
    program = loadShaders("gears.vert", "gears.frag");
    glUseProgram(program);
    glUniform4fv(glGetUniformLocation(program, "pos"), 1, pos);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(program, "projectionMatrix"), 1, GL_TRUE, projectionMatrix);
    colorPos = glGetUniformLocation(program, "color");
    gVert = new float[size];
    gNorm = new float[size];
    float *pts = new float[vDensity*hDensity*4];
    float *norm = new float[vDensity*hDensity*4];
    int num = cloth1.drawShaded(gVert, gNorm);
    cloth1.getPoints(pts,norm);
    fbo1 = initFBO(hDensity, vDensity, 0,pts,norm);
    fbo2 = initFBO(hDensity, vDensity, 0,pts,norm);

    glGenVertexArrays(1, &clothVao);
    glBindVertexArray(clothVao);
    glGenBuffers(1, &clothVbo);
    glGenBuffers(1, &clothNbo);
    glGenBuffers(1, &clothTbo);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, clothVbo);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, num*9*sizeof(GLfloat), gVert, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glVertexAttribPointer(glGetAttribLocation(program, "in_Position"), 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0); 
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(glGetAttribLocation(program, "in_Position"));


    //VAO for quad
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &quadVao);
    glBindVertexArray(quadVao);

    //VBO for quad
    glGenBuffers(1, &quadVbo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, quadVbo);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(quad), quad, GL_STATIC_DRAW);


    glBindVertexArray(0);

    delete [] gVert;
    delete [] gNorm;


    //texture
    texture_img = loadTexture("C:/Users/Bohb/Downloads/boa.jpg");

    location_Texture = glGetUniformLocation( program, "colorMap" );
    if(location_Texture == -1)
        fprintf( stderr, "Binding warning: Failed to locate uniform variable 'colorMap'.\n");

    frustum(-1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 5.0, 60.0, projectionMatrix);

    startTime = glutGet(GLUT_ELAPSED_TIME) / 1000.0;
    glBindVertexArray(clothVao);
}
```

Comment: In `drawClothGPU()`, you are doing something a little bit peculiar. Immediately after calling `glBindVertexArray (...)` you bind `quadVbo` to `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` for no apparent reason. Binding something to `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` should only be done if you are going to call `glVertexAttribPointer (...)`, the buffer bound to `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` actually does not affect draw calls in any way.

Comment: Alright, good to know! It doesn't solve the problem though.